# Using Python to count the number of lines in a CSV file where multiple titles contain information at the same time

Tags: python, csv, statistics

I need to count the number of lines in a CSV file where multiple titles contain information at the same time,

For example, this is my CSV file:

```
id,gender,name,age
1,M,Kerry Manders,
2,F,Cain Coulton,29
3,,Marcia Bennett,62
4,F,Rachel Werahiko,
5,,Karen Coulton,44
6,M,Sophia Shortcliffe,62
7,M,Files Access,30
8,,,39
```

Yes, there are some null values in CSV, and I need to calculate the number of rows with non null values in multiple titles. For example, I want to calculate the lines in the title that contain information about "gender" and "name"，

The answer is 6 lines. Of course, just tell it how many lines there are, no need to output the file

```
gender,name
M,Kerry Manders
F,Cain Coulton
F,Rachel Werahiko
M,Sophia Shortcliffe
M,Files Access
```

When I calculate 'gender', 'name', and 'age', Python calculates four lines

```
gender,name,age
F,Cain Coulton,29
M,Sophia Shortcliffe,62
M,Files Access,30
```

I tried to calculate the row containing information by searching for null values, but I don't know how to continue, or if you have other better methods

```
import csv
with open(r"C:\Users\o\Desktop\1.csv",'r',encoding='UTF-8') as load_input:
    with open(r"C:\Users\o\Desktop\2.csv", 'w', newline='',encoding='UTF-8') as out_output:
        ereader = csv.reader(load_input)
        ewriter = csv.writer(out_output)
        eheader = next(ereader)
        ewriter.writerow(eheader)
        for row_list in ereader:
            image_id = str(row_list[2]).strip()
            if '' in image_id:
                ewriter.writerow(row_list)
            elif '' in image_id:
                print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the input CSV as a sequence of dicts with `csv.DictReader` and count the number of dicts with all the desired columns non-empty. Add 1 to the count to include the header row for output:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

load_input = StringIO('''id,gender,name,age
1,M,Kerry Manders,
2,F,Cain Coulton,29
3,,Marcia Bennett,62
4,F,Rachel Werahiko,
5,,Karen Coulton,44
6,M,Sophia Shortcliffe,62
7,M,Files Access,30
8,,,39''')
query = ['gender', 'name', 'age']
print(sum(all(map(row.get, query)) for row in csv.DictReader(load_input)) + 1)
```

This outputs: `4`

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBBT8MwDIXv@RW@pRXWxNoxtsMOMDQJTRPSduCAEIpSt41Ik5CmoP364gJiJ0vP79mfHc6p9a5chTiOpgs@JtD9p6ij78B4@JNOKRrXPD4JYb2q3owLQ4LNv5xJKU2FDbmKIjrVEaqGxBwPuKcYz3BQU6dHUeAOt8o42PrBJu@wWIsS8aCiNgruyTlKCZeFWLDxqHRLFp4pqta8exQ3iHsV6ZJeLMSSl5x8aDl@aplVW1PXNI245c7OWOrhTmvqeyyvxQoRyzXj5uJjICbbwIv85ZYIckKfKtPLVxH4upT1Q5cpa7NOhSz6r1lDCeEnnOdQ@wgsAl/Eb5s9GJ2OpHhadnkU265gno/jNw)

Comment: It looks great, but how do I add CSV,```data=r'C:\\Users\\o\\Desktop\\1.csv'  load_input = StringIO(data)``` , so?

Comment: I used `io.StringIO` only for easier inline demonstration. To load the CSV content from a file simply do what you do with `open`: `with open(r"C:\Users\o\Desktop\1.csv",'r',encoding='UTF-8') as load_input:`

Comment: ```with open(r"C:\Users\o\Desktop\1.csv") as load_input:   load_input = StringIO()```  python output 1 . In any case, it only has 1 row,  I have been trying for a long time. Can you update the complete code

Comment: I mean, I used `io.StringIO` only for demonstration purposes, so that I can include the CSV content directly in the code I posted. You should not use `io.StringIO` at all. Just open the file normally: `with open(r"C:\Users\o\Desktop\1.csv",'r',encoding='UTF-8') as load_input: print(sum(all(map(row.get, query)) for row in csv.DictReader(load_input)) + 1)`

Comment: Oye, it's already working properly. Thank you